# HTTP to HTTPS redirect for only one URL

Tags: asp.net, http, redirect, iis-7, https

Was wondering if anybody could help. Thanks so much!

**Problem**:

- *blog.example.com*
- *cool.example.com*

  redirect to *https://www.example.com*

**Goal**:

We're trying to only redirect

- *http://example.com*
- *http://www.example.com*

  to *https://www.example.com*

**Current code**

Current code in web.config is this.  Stuck on `<match url="(.*)">`

Below is rest of rewrite rule.

```
<system.webServer>     
 <rewrite>
    <rules>
       <rule name="Redirect to https">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
             <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="443" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com" />
       </rule>
    </rules>
 </rewrite>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
  <files>
    <clear/>    
    <!--Remove this line or place below to deprecate-->
    <add value="default.aspx"/>
    <add value="index.html"/>
    <add value="index.php"/>
    <add value="default.html"/>
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify `<match url="(.*)" />` to include only `example.com` and `www.example.com` - right now you're matching all urls.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/

Comment: I'm not too familiar with regex. Do you mean this `<match url="(example.com)+(www.example.com)" />` ?

Comment: You can use regex or wildcards - I always use UI to setup the rules, much easier this way ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry, would you mind sending me a URL where I can learn how to write this rule? What's UI?

Comment: UI - user interface - you can setup rules in IIS.

Comment: Thanks. I thought UI was some regex term. :p

Comment: This is what I ended up with that works  `<match url="(.*)example(.*)" />`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<rule name="Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="false" enabled="false">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" type=”Pattern” pattern="^(www\.)?example.com$">
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
```

Comment: -1 - how this is NOT going to redirect for `blog.example.com`?

Comment: The point was to show a working rule (that has a different condition for capturing non-https traffic) that could be fine-tuned as directed in the comment.

Comment: Understood.  And it is impossible to prove a successful rule without being in the environment.  The point was to start with a working loose, rule and tweak it with obvious changes (as mentioned above) to tighten it up.

Comment: Updated with specific solution